# ContourPlot does not find contours that RegionPlot finds

Tags: plotting

For a function I am plotting I can get a `RegionPlot[f[x, y] > 100]` but if I do `ContourPlot[f[x, y], Contours -> {1, 10, 100, 1000}]` in the same $x$ and $y$ ranges, only the contours for 1 and 10 are drawn, not the ones for 100 and 1000. I know that these two contours exists because `RegionPlot` finds them, so, what options of `ContourPlot` should I use to get the plot done?

For an example please try `ContourPlot[0.000157223 10^(2 x - 2 y), {x, -6, -1}, {y, -6, -1}, Contours -> { 100}, ContourShading -> False]`

Comment: So, um, can I see what `f` looks like?  :-)

Comment: try `PlotPoints`

Comment: @JasonB The specific f I have today is something you do not want to look at :) it comes from a long manipulation of inputs.

Comment: @george2079 Thanks, I tried that, and `MaxRecursion` but they are of no help here. It only helps if I do the plot in a smaller range in which the contours end up being. In the original range the contours would be only in the lower right part of the frame.

Comment: @RobertoFranceschini - you could execute `CopyToClipboard[f[x,y]]` and then go to gist.github.com and paste it there.  That way we can work with the function without having to really look at it

Comment: Roberto, as you can see, we are shooting blind here. We need to have access to the function, or even better, to a minimal working example that exhibits the same problem, to provide meaningful help.

Comment: You can use this one `0.000157223 10^(2 x -2 y) ` and compare `RegionPlot[
 0.000157223 10^(2 x - 2 y) > 100, {x, -6, -1}, {y, -6, -1}]` and 
`ContourPlot[0.000157223 10^(2 x - 2 y), {x, -6, -1}, {y, -6, -1}, 
 Contours -> { 100}, ContourShading -> False]`

Comment: Interestingly, `ContourPlot[0.000157223 10^(2 x - 2 y) == 100, {x, -6, -1}, {y, -6, -1}]` does plot the contour.

Comment: @Rahul that's true! quite weird to me. Any reason why this should be different?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, what's happening is that the contour you want is outside the automatically chosen `PlotRange`. Observe:

```
ContourPlot[0.000157223 10^(2 x - 2 y), {x, -6, -1}, {y, -6, -1}]
```

[image]

The contour you want would be in the white part, whose values are extremely high compared to the automatically drawn contours. Instead you have to force the `PlotRange` to contain the contour, for example by setting it to `All`:

```
ContourPlot[0.000157223 10^(2 x - 2 y), {x, -6, -1}, {y, -6, -1}, Contours -> {100},
 ContourShading -> None, PlotRange -> {Full, Full, All}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting as answer! (+1)

Answer (score 5):

Working blind.. here is a little trick to let you visualize where `ContourPlot` evaluates your function and help you find appropriate settings for `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`.  I think `MaxRecursion` doesn't help if it doesn't even spot the countour on first pass.

```
cv = 3/4;
Show[
 MapAt[Graphics[{If[#[[3]] > cv, Red, Blue], 
       Point[#[[1 ;; 2]]]} & /@ #[[1]]] &,
  Reap[ContourPlot[  (fv = Sin[x] Cos[y]) == cv , 
      {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4},
    EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y, fv}],
    MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 5]], {2}]]
```

[image]

Applying this to your example,

```
cv = 100;
Show[
 MapAt[Graphics[{If[#[[3]] > cv, Red, Blue], 
       Point[#[[1 ;; 2]]]} & /@ #[[1]]] &,
  Reap[ContourPlot[
    fv = 0.000157223 10^(2 x - 2 y), {x, -6, -1}, {y, -6, -1}, 
    Contours -> {1, 10, 100, 1000}, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, y, fv}], 
    ContourShading -> None]], {2}]]
```

[image]

you see it is finding the contours just fine so it seems like a glitch in contourshading.  (I tried playing with `ContourStyle` with no success )

As noted by @Rahul in comments this works:

```
ContourPlot[ 0.000157223 10^(2 x - 2 y) == {1, 10, 100,  1000},
  {x, -6, -1}, {y, -6, -1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With shading and legend.

```
ContourPlot[0.00015 10^(2 x - 2 y), {x, -6, -1}, {y, -6, -1}, 
 Contours -> {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000},
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["StarryNightColors"][Rescale[Log10[#], {0, 6}]] &),
 PlotRange -> Full,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]